# vim text replacement : :%s/é/&&eacute/g foreign language

Tags: vim

I have a text with multiple french character: I'm trying to replace all the occurrences for an HTML code

example `été` to get => `&eacute;t&eacute;`
right now I'm having either error or a weird text

```
:%s/é/&&eacute;/g  => this gives me a ééeacute;tééeacute;
:%s/é/&&eacute;/g  => this gives me a éeacute;téeacute;
:%s/é//&eacute;/g  => this gives me an error Trailling character
```

Comment: Have you tried `:%s/é/\&eacute;/g` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the replacement part, `&` is special, it represents the whole match:

```
J'ai mangé du paté de campagne.

:s/é/&&acute;/g
J'ai mangéacute; du patéeacute; de campagne.
```

Escape it to obtain the desired `&`:

```
:s/é/\&acute;/g
J'ai mang&acute; du pat&eacute; de campagne.
```

Comment: thanks but I'm getting the same error that I had previously. `mangéacute;`